# How to insert an undered list into jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a site that uses a jquery script to show a video on the homepage for desktops and an image for mobiles.  I am trying to replace the single image for mobiles with a slider instead to have more images.  The slider markup is in a ul list form. You can see the image (`header_video_image.jpg`) for mobiles on in the snippet of the jquery script below on line #9

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var BV = new $.BigVideo({
                            container:$('#top-images'),
                            controls:false
                        });
        BV.init();
if (Modernizr.touch) {
BV.show("{{ 'header_video_image.jpg' | asset_url }}");
} else {
        BV.show([
            { type: "video/mp4",  src: "/assets/home-video.mp4" },
            { type: "video/webm", src: "/assets/home-video.webm" },
            { type: "video/ogg",  src: "/assets/home-video.ogv" }
        ],{doLoop:true});
}
    });
</script>
```

I want to replace `header_video_image.jpg` with the following ul list:

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
  <li><img src="img/qz3b0o.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="img/2e54mc0.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="img/qz3b0o.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({
                        container:$('#top-images'),
                        controls:false
                    });
    BV.init();
    if (Modernizr.touch) {

        // BV.show("{{ 'header_video_image.jpg' | asset_url }}");

        var mobileSlider = '<ul class="rslides hide" id="slider1">';
        mobileSlider += '<li><img src="img/qz3b0o.jpg" alt=""></li>';
        mobileSlider += '<li><img src="img/2e54mc0.jpg" alt=""></li>';
        mobileSlider += '<li><img src="img/qz3b0o.jpg" alt=""></li>';
        mobileSlider += '</ul>';

        BV.show( 100, function() {$( this ).html( mobileSlider );});

    } else {
            BV.show([
                { type: "video/mp4",  src: "/assets/home-video.mp4" },
                { type: "video/webm", src: "/assets/home-video.webm" },
                { type: "video/ogg",  src: "/assets/home-video.ogv" }
            ],{doLoop:true});
    }
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I made a jsbin with a similar answer: https://jsbin.com/yamejo/edit?js,output

Comment: Hi Pete, it didn't work at all. The picture is supposed to display on mobiles and it does but when I replace it with your code to insert the slider there's no longer a picture or a slider. See here: http://wap9.info/6328

Comment: Pat Diola's solution didn't do anything either, I was unable to see a slider with the John Wayne images he used in the jsbin